# How can I remove the * from radio buttons using BoostrapVue?

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

I have a [radio group](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio#grouped-radios) that contains several items.

```
<template>
    <b-form-group label="Is this working properly?" required>
        <b-form-radio-group v-model.trim="selected" :options="myOptions" />               
    </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
...
data() {
    return {
        selected: "",
        myOptions: [
            {text: 'Yes', value: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No', value: 'no'},
        ],
    }
}
...
</script>
```

When the radio button renders, the `*` is covering the actual input.

Inspecting the css, I can see these are the rules for this input:

```
.form-group[required] label::before, .form-group[required] legend::before {
    color: #C62140;
    content: "*";
}
```

Since I want the `*` to show on the legend (Is this working properly?) I know I need to override only labels that are adjacent to the input.

I have been working with different variations of this:

```
.form-group[required] input[type="radio"] + label::before {
    content: "",
}
```

This is what the rendered component looks like:

[image]

The generated markup looks like this:

```
<fieldset data-v-bfaef99a="" class="form-group" required="required" id="__BVID__59">
    <legend tabindex="-1" class="bv-no-focus-ring col-form-label pt-0" id="__BVID__59__BV_label_">Is this working properly?</legend>
    <div>
        <div data-v-bfaef99a="" role="radiogroup" tabindex="-1" class="bv-no-focus-ring" id="__BVID__60">
            <div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="yes" id="__BVID__60_BV_option_0" name="__BVID__60">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__60_BV_option_0">
                    <span>Yes</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="no" id="__BVID__60_BV_option_1" name="__BVID__60">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__60_BV_option_1">
                    <span>No</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I feel like I've tried every combination of `input[type="radio"] + label` I can think of (other than the correct one) & it's driving me crazy.

How can I remove the `*` from within the radio buttons? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap do you have installed?

Comment: `"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2"`

Comment: I've updated to:
`"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",` and am seeing the same results.

Comment: BootstrapVue doesn't support Bootstrap 5, so you should definitely revert that. Where is that CSS that's causing issues coming from? I don't particularly remember ever seeing that in Bootstrap?

Comment: It looks like it's coming from Bootstrap when it gets injected into the head of my main html file.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'm not seeing it in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hiws/pen/XWeyEoB), which is the HTML you pasted, with Bootstrap `4.6.0` and BootstrapVue `2.21.2` CSS included.